# It is possible to manually control tooltips in Windows 8 Store Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a custom control. Can I show tooltip where I want and when I want? [TooltipService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice) and [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip) classes don't help me, because don't contain appropriate members. Is there another way to implement custom tooltips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the ToolTip can be opened programmatically by setting IsOpen, and besides the top/left/bottom/right placement modes which are ideal for touch users, the mouse placement mode can position a tool tip relative to the touch/mouse point.  If the provided tooltip placement modes don't suffice for your scenario, use a Popup (ToolTip uses one under the hood).

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. I'll investigate using Popup for realizing custom tooltip.

Comment: I've realized custom tooltips using Popup.